# How do I assign a shortcut to something if it isn't listed in User Preferences' shortcut list?

Tags: customization, selection-tools, shortcut

I'm trying to assign a shortcut on the user preferences to the "select pattern" command, but it doesn't seem to exist.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *Input* panel in the *User Preferences* is for searching for shortcuts *that already exist*. As there isn't a shortcut for *Select Pattern* already, it won't appear in there.

To add a shortcut, go to the menu where *Select Pattern* is (*Object Mode> Select> Select Pattern...*), right-click and choose *Add Shortcut*. After entering a shortcut it will now be present in the *User Preferences* when you search for it.